# creating an executable of a python application using py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I'm stuck with creating an executable of my python program. My setup for creating an executable is as shown below,

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
project = dict(script="smarttester.py",
      dest_base="Smart Tester",
      uac_info="requireAdministrator")
console = [project]

setup(
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = "executable with privileges",
    console = console,
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    zipfile = None
     )
```

I'm receiving an error showing as,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\mypath\to\createexe.py", line 14, in <module>
         options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
     File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 162, in setup
          raise SystemExit, error
 SystemExit: error: MSVCP90.dll: No such file or directory
```

Looking for a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: For solutions, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158705/msvcp90-dll-not-found